# Return stemmed word in Solr

Tags: solr

We have stemming in our Solr search and we need to retrieve the word/phrase after stemming. That is if I search for "oranges", through stemming a search for "orange" is carried out. If I turn on debugQuery I would be able to see this, however we'd like to access it through the result if possible. Basically, we need this, because we pass the searched word as a parameter to a 3rd party application which highlights the word in an online PDF reader. Currently, if a user searches for "oranges" and a document contains "orange", then the PDF wouldn't highlight anything since it tries to highlight "oranges" not "orange".

Thanks all in advance,

Krt_Malta

Comment: how are you accessing solr? if you use the solrj java library, you can apparently access highlighting as described at the bottom of this page: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Reading_Data_from_Solr

Comment: We use an API which is based on SolrJ, so this could be useful. What does highlightSnippets actually return?

Comment: try it out in the solr admin form: ...solr/icom/admin/form.jsp. Set highlighting to enabled and select your field: the response includes a set of "highlighting" elements that you can parse.

Comment: We have the same problem: we need the stemmed word and additional all the aliases solr used for the search to bring those words to an 3rd party highlightner. Do you have any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with Solr but if you need it just for presentation to users you could stem their queries using the same stemmer Solr uses yourself. This would probably be faster since it would avoid a trip to Solr's index. For English this would presumably be http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/ - or you could check Solr's implementation.

However, a word of caution, most stemming algorithms do not guarantee that stemmed words will be actual words. Check here http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/english/stemmer.html for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the implicit [analysis request handler](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/implicit-requesthandlers.html#analysis-handlers) to get the stemmed word.

For your example, if you are using the `text_en` field and the Snowball Stemmer, the URL

```
<YOUR SOLR HOST>/solr/<YOUR COLLECTION>/analysis/field?analysis.query=oranges&analysis.fieldtype=text_en&verbose_output=1
```

would give you a json response, including the following:

```
"org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.SnowballFilter",
      [
        {
          "text": "orang",
             ...
```